# How to edit an inline message in aiogram telegrambot

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

An inline message is sent when the **result** is displayed inline and should change after 1 second!
Can **Aiogram** use `edit_message()`

```
@dp.inline_handler()
async def inline_echo(inline_query: types.InlineQuery):
    print(inline_query)
    text = inline_query.query or 'You'
    input_content = types.InputTextMessageContent(text)
    item = types.InlineQueryResultArticle(
        id=inline_query.id,
        thumb_url="https://t.me/iCoderNet",
        title=f'I ❤️ {text!r}',
        input_message_content=input_content,
    )
    #RESULT
    await inline_query.answer(results=[item], cache_time=1)
    #EDIT
    sleep(2)
    await bot.edit_message_text("❤️", inline_message_id=id)
```

**Please explain how to Edit !!!**